# Pass v.cwiseAbs() to a function that accept Ref<VectorXd>

Tags: eigen, eigen3

The following does not seem to work.

```
void Foo(Ref<VectorXd> v) {
  // modifies v
}

Eigen::VectorXd v;
Foo(v.cwiseAbs());
```

With the following error message

> error: could not convert 'Eigen::ArrayBase::cwiseAbs() const with Derived = Eigen::ArrayWrapper, -1, 1, true>, -1, 1, false> >; Eigen::ArrayBase::CwiseAbsReturnType = Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp, const Eigen::ArrayWrapper, -1, 1, true>, -1, 1, false> > >; typename Eigen::internal::traits::Scalar = double' from 'const CwiseAbsReturnType {aka const Eigen::CwiseUnaryOp, const Eigen::ArrayWrapper, -1, 1, true>, -1, 1, false> > >}' to 'Eigen::Ref >'

Any suggestions why and how to fix?

Comment: What would you expect that to do?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work, because two additional `const` qualifiers are required in order to mach the expression returned by `.cwiseAbs()`. This makes sense, because it should not be possible to modify the result of `v.cwiseAbs()` by a function that accepts this argument in the form of a reference. The following code compiles:

```
void Foo(const Ref<const VectorXd>& v) {
  std::cout << v << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  Eigen::VectorXd v(3);
  v << 1,-2,3;
  Foo(v.cwiseAbs());
}
```

With this modification, however, it is not allowed to modify `v` within `Foo()`.

The simplest solution is probably to drop `Ref<>` and to use

```
 Foo(VectorXd v) {...}
```

instead. This generates a local copy, but this should not be an issue in terms of performance, moreover since it is anyhow impossible to avoid any copy if `v` is to be modified within `Foo()`. If `Ref` is kept in the signature of `Foo`, one can make a copy of `v.cwiseAbs()` and call `Foo()` with that copy:

```
void Foo(Ref<VectorXd> v) {...}
...
Eigen::VectorXd w = v.cwiseAbs();
Foo(w);
```

As suggested by @chtz, an alternative that is available with C++11 is

```
void Foo(VectorXd&& v) {...}
```

While this allows to modify `v` within `Foo()`, it can be somewhat dangerous to use because only a temporary is changed in `Foo()`. Modifications of `v` done in `Foo()` will not change `v` in `main()`.

Comment: Instead of `const Ref<const VectorXd> v` it is suggested to use `const Ref<const VectorXd> &v` (since `Ref<const X>` can hold a temporary, which makes copying expensive, though in practice this will usually (hopefully) be optimized away). And with C++11 an alternative would be `void Foo(VectorXd&& v)` this would allow modifying `v`, but very often one would just edit a temporary (so be careful with using that).

Comment: Thanks for the insights! Is `Foo(VectorXd v)` a good solution? I guess for this case it is fine as it makes one copy just like the solutions above? For other cases e.g. `v.block()` it makes one copy while `Ref<>` does not? Any particular reason to favor `Foo(VectorXd&&)` over `Foo(VectorXd)`? Thanks!

Comment: I think `Foo(VectorXd)` is the way to go here. In general, references are useful in order to (a) avoid a copy and thereby improve performance and/or (b) return a modified version of the argument (`v`) to the main code after exiting the function. Since (b) is not allowed here and (a) is not likely to be a critical point, I'd drop the `Ref` and use `Foo(VectorXd v)`. Not sure about a possible advantage of `Foo(VectorXd&&)` but I think that it could be somewhat faster because it uses a temporary instead of copying the data to a new object.  Not worth the complication regarding the syntax, IMHO.

Comment: @bill what behavior do you actually want? Why do you want to modify `v`? If it shall not have a side effect on the caller, you can pass a `const MatrixBase<Derived>&` and copy that to a local variable. Passing by value does have the advantage that you could explicitly `std::move` variables which you don't need anymore to the function, though.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the insights! The real problem is to have a quantile function foo (the best I can think of is with std::nth_element, which modifies input), and its main usage is foo(v.abs()) or foo(v.col(j).head(n).abs()).

Comment: @bill there is no (practical) solution such that calling `foo(v.abs())` actually modifies `v` (I guess you also don't need that?) If the caller does not care about what happens with the object it passes to `foo`, I'd tend to write `foo(VectorXd&&)`. If you want to still use the (modified) object after calling `foo`, or you want to avoid allocating a new vector, I'd write `foo(Ref<VectorXd>)` and call it like: `v = v.cwiseAbs(); foo(v);` or `v.head(n) = v.head(n).cwiseAbs(); foo(v.head(n));`